# Android How to show user name and profile in post

Tags: java, android, api, backend

Am wonder if anyone can solve my issue since i entered in android developers field i have this question running on my mind always

I have 2 tables one for post and another One for user details

A user posted hundred post and more than hundred comments  i want to show their name and profile pic in each comment and  post

If my user update his name or profile photo I want to update them in comments and post how can i do that ? If i update them one by one comment and post it will cost me a lot of writes or if i call my user table for each post and each comments the it will cost me lot of reads and api calls what is the proper way to do that?

Comment: A comment should probably only have an identifier pointing towards the author, not towards a profile photo or username.

Comment: So you dont want to fetch username and DP by force refresh ?